# How to clean a string from non-alphanumeric characters, but keep certain ones?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that has non-alphanumeric characters, this string contains English and non English alphabets. I need to clean the string from non-alphanumeric characters, but I want to keep some of them. For instance: Let's say that I want to keep comma and colon only.

Example:
`String st = "I, Love: ( Coding {}+-), codificación"`

I want the output to be `"I,Love:Coding,codificación"`

Is there a regex that can do that?

Note the method below will clean the text from all non-alphanumeric characters.

```
public static String cleanText(String text) {
     return text.replaceAll("\\P{LD}+", "");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
public static String cleanText(String text) {
    return text.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}:,]+", "");
    // or return text.replaceAll("[^\\p{LD}:,]+", "");
}
```

*Details*:

- `[^` - start of a negated character class

  - `\p{L}` - any Unicode letter
  - `\p{N}` - any digit
  - `:` - a colon
  - `,` - a comma
- `]+` - end of the character class, repeat one or more times.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DwogV1/1). See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/yYBwHv):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String st = "I, Love: ( Coding {}+-), codificación";
        System.out.println(cleanText(st));

    }
    public static String cleanText(String text) {
        return text.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}:,]+", "");
    }
}
// => I,Love:Coding,codificación
```